# How to deploy express app on firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have built an express app and the folder structure is below.

[image: as follows]

Then i created firebase init hosting on a dummy folder and copied the firebase.json and .firebase files

I created **index.js** file

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions')
    const app = require('./app');
    exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrite":[{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "widgets"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Also copied the index.html generated by firebase to public folder

[image]

On deployment i am getting index.html

[image]

If i delete index.html and run as localhost i am getting below output

[image]

How can i get the express app executed (as shown in localhost) instead of index.html on firebase deploy.

**Edit 1**

I am following [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

When i run **firebase serve**, i am getting this error

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: missing path at Module.require (module.js:583:3) at require (internal/module.js:11:18) at InitializeFirebaseAdminStubs (C:\Users\alaksandarjesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:231:18) at C:\Users\alaksandarjesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:451:9 at Generator.next () at C:\Users\alaksandarjesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71 at new Promise () at __awaiter (C:\Users\alaksandarjesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12) at main (C:\Users\alaksandarjesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:421:12) at Object. (C:\Users\alaksandarjesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:511:5)
```

When i tried to run **firebase deploy**

```
E:\ogst-server-firebase\functions>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'ogst-server-95fcc'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

The reason for this is missing public folder, and i created manually (which was expected to be created with firebase init functions).

```
E:\ogst-server-firebase\functions>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'ogst-server-95fcc'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  hosting[ogst-server-95fcc]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[ogst-server-95fcc]: found 0 files in public
+  hosting[ogst-server-95fcc]: file upload complete
i  hosting[ogst-server-95fcc]: finalizing version...
+  hosting[ogst-server-95fcc]: version finalized
i  hosting[ogst-server-95fcc]: releasing new version...
+  hosting[ogst-server-95fcc]: release complete

+  Deploy complete!

Please note that it can take up to 30 seconds for your updated functions to propagate.
Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/ogst-server-95fcc/overview
Hosting URL: https://ogst-server-95fcc.firebaseapp.com
```

Now my deployment is successful. But i am getting 404

**Answer**
In the index.js file (following the above link), i did not change

```
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(app); //wrong

to

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app); //correct
```

Thanks to all for the support

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting prefers to serve static content over rewrites that get sent to Cloud Functions.  In other words, if a request could be served by any static content, that content will always take precedence over a rewrite to Cloud Functions.

If you want your web site root page to be served by Cloud Functions, this means you should not have an index.html in your public folder, since Firebase Hosting is finding that first.

Comment: Then that's probably what your express app is serving.

Comment: no..if i delete index.html and run npm start, i am getting my express app executed.

Comment: `npm start` isn't part of a workflow that involves Firebase Hosting.  You need to use the Firebase CLI to start emulating Firebase Hosting and its rewrites. `firebase serve` starts that.  Please go over the documentation for Hosting to better understand that.

Comment: can u check out my Edit 1 please

Comment: Thanks i fixed it